# How do I show all child objects in a template?

Tags: django, django-models

These are my models.py

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    costprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
    retailprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=99, unique=True, blank=True)
    image = DefaultStaticImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                                default='images/item_gC0XXrx.png')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

I have a supplierpage/str:pk_supplier/ and inside it I want to display all products that belong to that specific supplier in a table like:

```
<tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Retail Price</th>
      <th>Barcode</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
  **{% for ??? in ???? %} <-----what should i put here??**

      <td> <a href="{% url 'productpage' product.id %}">{{product.id}}</a></td>
      <td><h6><strong>{{product.description}}</strong></h6></td>
      <td>£{{product.costprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
      <td>£{{product.retailprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
      <td>{{product.barcode}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share your view.

Comment: if you are sending `supplier_instance = Supplier.objects.get(id=something)` to template then use `{% for product in supplier_instance.product_set.all %}` upvote if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you can filter on the `pk_supplier`, so:

```
def my_view(request, pk_supplier):
    products = Product.objects.filter(supplier_id=pk_supplier)
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'products': products})
```

In the template, you then enumerate over your `products`:

```
{% for product in products %}
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="{% url 'productpage' product.id %}">{{product.id}}</a></td>
    <td><h6><strong>{{product.description}}</strong></h6></td>
    <td>£{{product.costprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
    <td>£{{product.retailprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
    <td>{{product.barcode}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```